# How to make UITableView rearrangeable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make my UITableView editable so you can move the cells around. Right now when I click the edit button, it only lets me delete but not re-arrange.

The methods I have are:

```
Code:
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
     {
         NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
         [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
         NSLog(@"fetched results : \n%@\n",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

         NSError *error = nil;

         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
         {
             // Handle the error.
         }
    }

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to implement reordering rows correctly, the table view data source should implement methods like :

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
       toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath;
```

and the its delegate could implement :

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
                     toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath;
```

There is also this [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW4) giving you examples of code.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html). You can also get the related sample code there.

> When a table view enters editing mode and when users drag a reordering
>   control, the table view sends a series of messages to its data source
>   and delegate, but only if they implement these methods. These methods
>   allow the data source and delegate to restrict whether and where a row
>   can be moved as well to carry out the actual move operation.